# how to create the data field for using in post of the retrofit2 if they have nested array

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

trying to port direct okHttp3 post to using retrofit2, (using sample from Lars Vogel’s http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html)

suppose the post’s data body should be look like:

```
{
'winCondition': 'HIGH_SCORE',
'name': 'Bowling',
'round': 4,
'lastSaved': 1367702411696,
'dateStarted': 1367702378785,
'players': [{
    'name': 'Jesse',
    'history': [10, 8, 6, 7, 8],
    'color': -13388315,
    'total': 39
}, {
    'name': 'Jake',
    'history': [6, 10, 5, 10, 10],
    'color': -48060,
    'total': 41
}]
}
```

the code snippet below shows the api end point and the post body (incomplete)
not sure how to write the data fields if there are array and pass to the function,

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("/post")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> savePost(@Field("winCondition") String winCondition,
                    @Field("name") String name,
                    @Field("round") Integer round,
                    @Field("lastSaved") Long lastSaved,
                    @Field("dateStarted") Long dateStarted 

                    /*how to make the sub array dat fields ??? */

   );

}




APIService svr = RetrofitClient.getClient("http://www.roundsapp.com/").create(APIService.class);

svr.savePost("HIGH_SCORE", 
                     "Bowling", 
                     4, 
                    1367702411696, 
                    1367702378785).enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Post> {
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<Post>, response: retrofit2.Response<Post>) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "+++ post submitted to API, isSuccessful:" + response.body().toString())
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "+++ !!! post submitted to API, isSuccessful:" + response.toString())
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<Post>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ Unable to submit post to API. onFailure:"+t.toString())
        }
    })
```

Comment: It is mandatory to pass your request as `@FormUrlEncoded` or you can pass `@Body` ? Check My gist : https://gist.github.com/pranaypatel512/2c9bd11fefb19f6b9a3895bed9ee77f1 . I have created for you.

Comment: thanks pRaNaY! using your class and pass the data as 
      'AT'FormUrlEncoded
      Call<Post> savePost('AT'Body RequestClass yourRequestClassObject); 
  it does not work:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'AT'Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding,   if without the  'AT'FormUrlEncoded it does not throw but the response is not successful.     And the payload does need encode. (sorry for using 'AT' for the 'at' char, cant type in)

Comment: Then just pass array list as  `@Field("players[]") ArrayList<Player> players` Check : http://johnsonsu.com/android-retrofit-posting-array/

Comment: @pRanaY, your idea of 'at'Body works. If you can put in a answer I will 'accept' it. Thanks!

Comment: if your answer is working fine then it is ok. or you can update it if require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on pRaNaY's suggestion of @Body, made it work with the following code.

but still got error of:

```
onFailure:com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $, the call:Request{method=POST, url=http://www.roundsapp.com/post, tag=null}
```

The error is the server's response is a simple plain string, unrelate to posting array, so it can be ignorered here

```
var okhtpp_ur_useJsonObjectlService = ApiUtils.getOKHttpAPI_newUsingJsonObjService()

    var rquestObj = generateRequest()

    okhtpp_ur_useJsonObjectlService!!.savePost(rquestObj).enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<String> {
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<String>, response: retrofit2.Response<String>) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString())
            } 
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<String>, t: Throwable) {}
    })

//////

private fun generateRequest(): JsonObject {
    var requestJsonObject = JSONObject()
    try {

        requestJsonObject.put("winCondition", "HIGH_SCORE")
        requestJsonObject.put("name", "Bowling")
        requestJsonObject.put("round", 4)
        requestJsonObject.put("lastSaved", 1367702411696)
        requestJsonObject.put("dateStarted", 1367702378785)

        var playersJsonArrayObject = JSONArray()

        var player1JsonObject = JSONObject()

        player1JsonObject.put("name", "Jess")
        var histryArray = JSONArray()
        histryArray.put(10)  
        histryArray.put(8)
        histryArray.put(6)
        histryArray.put(7)
        histryArray.put(8)
        player1JsonObject.put("history", histryArray)
        player1JsonObject.put("color", -13388315)
        player1JsonObject.put("total", 39)

        var player2JsonObject = JSONObject()

        player2JsonObject.put("name", "Jake")
        var histryArray2 = JSONArray()
        histryArray2.put(6)
        histryArray2.put(10)
        histryArray2.put(5)
        histryArray2.put(10)
        histryArray2.put(10)
        player2JsonObject.put("history", histryArray2)
        player2JsonObject.put("color", -48060)
        player2JsonObject.put("total", 41)

        playersJsonArrayObject.put(player1JsonObject)
        playersJsonArrayObject.put(player2JsonObject)

        requestJsonObject.put("players", playersJsonArrayObject)            
    } catch (e: Exception) {            e.printStackTrace()
    }
    var jsonParser = JsonParser();
    var gsonObject: JsonObject = jsonParser.parse(requestJsonObject.toString()) as JsonObject
    return gsonObject;
}


public interface UsingJsonObjectAPIService {
    @Headers({
        "Content-Type: text/plain"
    })
    @POST("/post")
    Call<String> savePost(@Body JsonObject requestClassObject);  

}
```